# mongodb not starting on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm running ubuntu 18.04 on windows 10. I run 'mongod' on cli and mongodb starts normally. I then try to run 'mongo' and I get this error :

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-09-01T20:30:37.462+0800 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed.
```

I don't understand how one works and the other doesn't. I do think it is from either file permissions or an issue with the localhost.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a couple things

1.) Make sure you have the /data/db directory set up.

2.) start mongodb with sudo

```
sudo start mongodb
```

or

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

3.) You might have to remove a lock file try the following:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
```

4.) Repair your mongodb instance

```
sudo mongod --repair
```

5.) Try running the mongo console:

```
mongo
```

6.)Check the status of the mongodb instance

```
sudo status mongodb
```

If these don't work I know DigitalOcean has a great tutorial which I have linked [Digital_Ocean_Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: On trying to run "sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock" I am getting  "No such file or directory. Can you suggest what went wrong here?

Comment: you might not need to run the command to remove the lock file? Are you getting an error as well?

Comment: I am getting the following error if I skip step 3 and run 1,2,4 and 5:    "W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused" .     "E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed"

Comment: maybe run a sudo service mongod restart and make sure in your mongod.conf file you have the bind_ip set

Comment: Do you have port forwarding to your machine from a remote host?

Comment: No I don't it might be helpful if you post a question!

Answer (score 0):

Restart mongodb service and Verify you have installed mongo client. In case you dont, install it.

1. sudo apt install -y mongodb
2. sudo systemctl restart mongodb

that's it.

Comment: This is old version of mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

First, try doing

```
sudo start mongodb
```

If that does not work, then you can try

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

But, I would suggest do not purge or remove mongo or mongodb, as it might cause you data loss.

And if **no other option** remains, what you can do is copy your following folder to another directory.

Suppose ,

you take copy of the folder from

> var/mongodb/lib/

and paste it to

> /Downloads/db_wt_backup/

the folder has .wt (WiredTiger) files for the DB.

Then you can remove/uninstall MongoDB completely with **Purge**

Then re-install it again and paste the data from **Downloads/db_wt_backup/** folder to **var/mongodb/lib/**

and then

```
sudo service mongodb start
```